# Cloud function being called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does a Firestore cloud function call itself?
I am trying to achieve the process below without it becoming a recursive function. For the cloud function to only be called once.

Process:

1: User updates a document from the client side.

2: Cloud function gets called, grabs a few users and updates their documents as well.

Since both updates (on the client side and on cloud function) use the same update path the function seems to be called 3 times somehow (when i console.log the process). Is this the expected behaviour? How can i safely call the function once without the risk of it being called multiple times.

```
exports.onUpdateEvent = functions.firestore
  .document("all_artists/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const updateData = change.after.data();

    const artistFollowersRef = admin.firestore().collection("artistFollowers");
    const querySnapshot = await artistFollowersRef.get();

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const userId = doc.id;
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("all_artists")
        .doc(userId)
        .update(updateData);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your foreach loop isn't going to work the way you expect because it's not waiting for each document to update before the function terminates. You will observe that some documents simply won't get updated when invoking this function, especially as the number of documents to update gets bigger.

Comment: You mean that i have to use sync/async and promises to handle this? do you have any example i an take a look at?

Comment: Do a web search for "javascript async await in foreach".

Answer (score 2):

If the Cloud Functions code writes to the document that triggered it, then indeed that'll cause it to be invoked again. Unless you guard against this, that will lead to an infinite loop.

Your functions triggers whenever any user document is updated, and it them updates all user documents in the same collection. This means that you can't prevent the invocations by using a different path in the trigger.

I'm not entirely sure what your function tries to accomplish, but a common way to prevent further invocations is to include a flag value in the data. For example, if you change the data you write to:

```
updateData.preventFurtherTriggers = true;
```

Then you can check for that flag immediately after getting the data, and exit early:

```
exports.onUpdateEvent = functions.firestore
  .document("all_artists/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const updateData = change.after.data();
    if (updateData.preventFurtherTriggers === true) return; // 

    ...
```

---

Note by the way that your function currently doesn't correctly return a Promise to signal that it is executing asynchronous operations. You'll want to read the documentation on [sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), and watch the videos in there, to learn how to address that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i am essentially trying to accomplish a many to many relationship with the cloud function. First grabbing users following an artist and then updated everyones data one by one. This however requires that the update path is the same. If i add the preventFurtherTriggers before any code i assume that it will exit on the second invocation of the cloud function then? Ill look into syn async and promises. Thank you for the advice.